# Apache Camel http4 POST throwing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-camel

i'm trying to read file with xml and then post it to URL using HTTP4. But keep getting the following exception.

i'm using Apache Camel version 2.11.0, with JDK 1.7 on Linux

Here is code:

```
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // create CamelContext
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        // add our route to the CamelContext
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("file:/home/projects/camelinaction-source/chapter1/file-copy/data/templates")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.POST))
                .to("http4://testserver:8080/rest/test")
                .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("response.xml"))
                .to("file:/home/projects/hyperlocal");
            }
        });

        // start the route and let it do its work
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // stop the CamelContext
        context.stop();
    }
```

Here is the exception.

```
    org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:283)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpEndpoint.createHttpClient(HttpEndpoint.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.<init>(HttpProducer.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpEndpoint.createProducer(HttpEndpoint.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:391)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.acquireProducer(ProducerCache.java:114)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.startProducer(ProducerCache.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.doStart(TraceInterceptor.java:358)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1064)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:28)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:153)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:85)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doStart(MulticastProcessor.java:938)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.doStart(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:322)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:151)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1986)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:1914)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1702)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1583)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1444)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1412)
    at camelinaction.FileCopierWithCamel.main(FileCopierWithCamel.java:52)
    ... 6 more
```

Here is the maven dependency i have in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It really does sound like you have mixed versions of Camel JARs on the classpath. Can you double check that all your Camel JARs is the same version?

Also you should have camel-http4 JAR on the classpath, and its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, you are right i found two different version of camel JARs on my machine.